# Insert all the attributes and values of JSON in to LUA table

Tags: json, lua

I would like to insert the attribute names and values of a JSON in to LUA table.

```
local function convert_table(tbl_test)
 local output_table = {}
  for i, v in pairs(tbl_test) do
    output_table [string.lower(i)] = string.lower(v)                     
  end  
 return output_table
end
  local  test  =  cjson.decode(inputJson)
  local  final =  convert_table(test)
```

This is working if my JSON is

```
 {    "test": "abc",
      "test1": "EDF",
      "test2": "PNG" }
```

But it is not working for below JSON (JSON inside a JSON)

```
{
  "upper": {
    "test": "abc",
    "test1": "EDF",
    "test2": "PNG",
  }, 
  "lower": {
    "test3": "aabc",
    "test4": "edfa",
    "test5": "png"
  }
}
```

Comment: `luarocks install cjson`

Comment: What did u get as result?
I'm using cjson aswell and it's working fine (business tools). U should get a nested  array.

Answer (score 1):

While it is *possible* to parse nested constructs like the above JSON example using Luas pattern maching, that's far from its intended purpose and generally just way to complicated for anything other than a dedicated library for that purpose.

A more viable solution:
Either use a more powerful tool like LPEG[¹](https://luarocks.org/modules/gvvaughan/lpeg) to build your parser (Which will still take some time), or just use any of the available json parsers for Lua[²](https://luarocks.org/modules/harningt/luajson) [³](https://luarocks.org/modules/openresty/lua-cjson).